# stm32L476 - erasing flash

Tags: stm32

The L4 series erases flash using pages (or banks, if you do a full erase).
But I'm having some problem writing after doing page erases, and I'm not sure why.

Just to outline the objective I am storing 6 values starting at 0x08080000 (Page 256)
then I am storing more values from 0x08080800) (page 257) to 0x08085800 (page 267)

There is a single function that I use to erase/write the values at page 256:

```
void write_bias_flash(int16_t biases[]) {
    uint16_t *flash_biases = (uint16_t*) (ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_256);
    static FLASH_EraseInitTypeDef EraseInitStruct;
    Address = ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_256;

    /* Fill EraseInit structure*/
    EraseInitStruct.TypeErase = FLASH_TYPEERASE_PAGES;
    EraseInitStruct.Page = 0;
    EraseInitStruct.Banks = FLASH_BANK_2;
    EraseInitStruct.NbPages = 1;

    HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
    if (HAL_FLASHEx_Erase(&EraseInitStruct, &PAGEError) != HAL_OK) {
        serprintf("Error erasing biases at address: 0x%x", Address);
    }
    for (int8_t bias = 0; bias < 6; bias++) {
         if (HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_DOUBLEWORD,
                Address + bias * sizeof(uint64_t), (uint64_t) biases[bias])
                != HAL_OK)
            serprintf("Error writing biases to flash.");
     }
    HAL_FLASH_Lock();
    serprintf("Biases stored in flash.");
}
```

This work great. No issues.

I have two functions I use to erase/write the data starting at 0x08080800) (page 257):

```
void Erase_TM_Flash() {
    uint8_t *flash = (uint8_t*) (FLASH_USER_START_ADDR);
    uint8_t *b = (uint16_t*) (ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_256);
    static FLASH_EraseInitTypeDef EraseInitStruct;
    Address = FLASH_USER_START_ADDR;

    /* Fill EraseInit structure*/
    EraseInitStruct.TypeErase = FLASH_TYPEERASE_PAGES;
    EraseInitStruct.Page = 1;
    EraseInitStruct.NbPages = 255;
    EraseInitStruct.Banks = FLASH_BANK_2;

    HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
    if (HAL_FLASHEx_Erase(&EraseInitStruct, &PAGEError) != HAL_OK) {
        serprintf("Error erasing biases at address: 0x%x", Address);
    }

    HAL_FLASH_Lock();

    for (uint16_t i = 0; i< (FLASH_ROW_SIZE * sizeof(uint64_t))*255; i++)
    {
        if ((uint16_t) *(flash+i) != 255) {
            serprintf("0x%x is not erased (%i)", flash+i, (uint16_t) *(flash+i));
        }

    }

}
void Save_to_Flash(uint32_t *data) {

    uint32_t src_addr = (uint32_t) data;
    Erase_TM_Flash();
    serprintf("Saving to flash...");
    HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_STATUS;

    HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
    Address = FLASH_USER_START_ADDR;
    while (Address < (FLASH_USER_END_ADDR - (FLASH_ROW_SIZE * sizeof(uint64_t)))) {
        HAL_STATUS = HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_FAST, Address, (uint64_t) src_addr);
        if (HAL_STATUS == HAL_OK) {
          Address = Addres+ (FLASH_ROW_SIZE * sizeof(uint64_t));
            src_addr = src_addr + (FLASH_ROW_SIZE * sizeof(uint64_t));
            } else {
                serprintf("Error writing flash at address 0x%x. (%i)", Address, HAL_STATUS);
                Address = Address + (FLASH_ROW_SIZE * sizeof(uint64_t));
                src_addr = src_addr + (FLASH_ROW_SIZE * sizeof(uint64_t));
            }
    }
    HAL_FLASH_Lock();
    serprintf("Done");
    }
```

The erase works fine.  I verify the values in the debugger (and in the code I check for non-erased pages). But when the saving occurs:

```
Error writing flash at address 0x8080800. (1)
Error writing flash at address 0x8080900. (1)
Error writing flash at address 0x8080a00. (1)
Error writing flash at address 0x8080b00. (1)
```

And so on through all the remaining pages.

However, if I erase the entire flash:

```
void Erase_Flash() {
    serprintf("Erasing flash...");
    HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
    /* Clear OPTVERR bit set on virgin samples */
    __HAL_FLASH_CLEAR_FLAG(FLASH_FLAG_OPTVERR);

    /* Fill EraseInit structure*/
    EraseInitStruct.TypeErase = FLASH_TYPEERASE_MASSERASE;
    EraseInitStruct.Banks = FLASH_BANK_2;

    if (HAL_FLASHEx_Erase(&EraseInitStruct, &PAGEError) != HAL_OK) {
        serprintf("Error erasing flash.");
    }
    HAL_FLASH_Lock();
    serprintf("Done.");
}
```

Then the writing works like a charm.
HAL_STATUS = 1, which according to the code I found is HAL_ERROR = 0x01U, which isn't entirely helpful.

I am not sure what the difference in, but I am hoping another set of eye on my erasure might reveal the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue seems to be related to flash fast programming, which isn't available on all STM32 models.

According to the [Reference Manual (RM0351)](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00083560-stm32l47xxx-stm32l48xxx-stm32l49xxx-and-stm32l4axxx-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf), the flash must be mass erased before using fast programming. Otherwise a **Programming Sequence Error** occurs, and the `PGSERR` bit in the `FLASH_SR` register will be set. See *3.3.7  Flash main memory programming sequences* in sections *Fast Programming* / *Programming errors* and *3.7.5  Flash status register (FLASH_SR)* under *Bit 7 PGSERR*.

RM0351 Rev 9, 3.3.7 Flash main memory programming sequences, on page 106:

```
Fast programming
(...)
1. Perform a mass erase of the bank to program. If not, PGSERR is set.
2. (...)
```

RM0351 Rev 9, 3.3.7 Flash main memory programming sequences, on page 107:

```
Programming errors
(...)
PGSERR: Programming Sequence Error
PGSERR is set if one of the following conditions occurs:
– (...)
– In the fast programming sequence: the Mass erase is not performed before setting 
  FSTPG bit.
– (...)
```

The observed behavior is therefore as expected. - So you could replace your `Erase_TM_Flash()` function and use `Erase_Flash()` to mass erase the entire flash bank first. Or, avoid using flash fast programming altogether and use `FLASH_Program_DoubleWord()` or `FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_DOUBLEWORD, ...)` instead.

Related source files: [stm32l4xx_hal_flash.h](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeL4/blob/master/Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/stm32l4xx_hal_flash.h), [stm32l4xx_hal_flash.c](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeL4/blob/master/Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_flash.c)

Related post: [STM32 - writing and reading flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68384037/stm32-writing-and-reading-flash#comment120876476_68384037)

Comment: Thank you!  I've been out of town and wasn't able to review this.  But it makes sense the way you've presented it.   I will have to reorganize some things.